# Best way divide a loop into threads?

Tags: concurrency, java-threads

I have a loop that repeats itself 8 times and I want to run each loop in a different thread so it will run quicker, I looked it up online but I can't decide for a way to do this. There are no shared resources inside the loop. Any ideas?
Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

The *best way* is to analyze your program for how it is to be used, and determine what the best cost vs performance trade off you can make is.   Threads, even in languages like go have a non-trivial overhead; and in languages like java, it can be a significant overhead.

You need to have a grasp upon what the cost of dispatching an operation onto a thread is versus the time to perform the operation, and what execution models you can apply to do so.   For example, if you try:

```
for (i = 0; i < NTHREAD; i++) {
      t[i] = create_thread(PerformAction, ...);
}
for (i = 0; i < NTHREAD; i++) {
      join_thread(t[i]);
}
```

You might think you have done wonderfully, however the NTHREAD-1’th thread doesn’t start until you have paid the overhead for creating the others.   In contrast, if you created threads in a tree-like structure, and your OS doesn’t blow, you can get a significantly lower latency.

So, best practise: measure, write for the generic case and configure for the specific one.